# Angular animation module slowing down web app performance

Tags: angular, performance

I am running performance profile on Angular application, I am seeing animation module which is responsible of slowing the application down. I have already removed animation dependency.

Why does it show up and how to effectively remove it? Also is anyone seeing more performance issues at first sight. Please let me know. But main concern in animation module.

From what i know removing dependency should remove animation module, is there any other way to force disable animation to boost performance.

[image]

App.module.ts

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "version": "1.2.10",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --output-hashing=all",
    "postbuild": "node licensify.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle": "bundlewatch",
    "bundle:report": "source-map-explorer dist/xyz/*.js",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run xyz:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/xyz/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all && ng run xyz:server",
    "build-custom:ssr": "ng build --configuration production --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --build-optimizer --source-map=false && ng run xyz:server && npm run postbuildCompress",
    "prerender": "ng run xyz:prerender",
    "build::brotli": "npm run build && npm run postbuildCompress",
    "postbuildCompress": "node brotli-compress.js",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
  "bundlewatch": {
    "files": [
      {
        "path": "./dist/xyz/*.js",
        "maxSize": "1mB"
      }
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^15.2.9",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.7.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.26",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "backoff-rxjs": "^6.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.9",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "exifreader": "^3.14.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^16.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  },
  "description": "Start project: (localhost:4200) ng serve",
  "main": "licensify.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```